# Can't connect to linux server from outside

Tags: linux, tcp, debian

I have a server running on a Linux/debian machine. I can GET/PUT correctly from within the same machine.

```
$ curl -v -X PUT -d "blabla" 127.0.1.1:5678
* About to connect() to 127.0.1.1 port 5678 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* connected
* Connected to 127.0.1.1 (127.0.1.1) port 5678 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: 127.0.1.1:5678
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 6
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 6 out of 6 bytes
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 405 Unsupported request method: "PUT"
< Connection: close
< Server: My Server v1.0.0
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

However if I try from another machine (same local network), here is what it says:

```
$ curl -v -X PUT -d "blabla" 192.168.0.21:5678
* About to connect() to 192.168.0.21 port 5678 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.21...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

From the server side, no firewall is running:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is what netcat reveals:

```
$ netstat -alnp | grep 5678
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:5678          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Is there a way to debug what could be going on ?

Comment: Check with `netstat -alnp | grep 5678` if the server program is actually listening on `192.168.0.21` or all interfaces (0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webapp is  listening on 127.0.0.1 which is loopback interface. In order to be accessible outside it would have  to be listening on 192.168.0.21:5678 or *:5678 which means all interfaces.

Comment: that was a default debian settings, pretty bad since I did not even installed GNOME (or any X env) on it.

Comment: you can edit config files on command line. you can use vi, nano, pico,emacs and so on.

Comment: The 127.0.1.1 mess was due to an issue in GNOME https://bugs.debian.org/719621 see my own answer.

Comment: I see. 127.0.1.1 should be 127.0.0.1, but it would still not be reachable outside. You need to make the webapp to bind on 192.168.0.21 or *

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out the [following line](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution):

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
#127.0.1.1  [...]
```

This is similar to my debian squeeze setup and appears to be working as expected. I have no clue why this extra line messed things up so badly. Apparently this is due to an [issue in GNOME](https://bugs.debian.org/719621) package, but this server does not even have X installed.